# Getting java class not found error in com/google/gson/jsonelement unable to initialize main class

Tags: python, java, jar

I am trying to read the jar file using python. when I try to read the same jar file through the command prompt it's working without any issue

```
java -cp jarfile;*;. com.help.someclass inputs inputs2
```

The same command when I try to run with Python using subprocess
I am getting an error

```
subprocess.popen(['java','-cp','jarfile',';*;.','com.help.someclass',input1,input2])
```

it's throwing "Unable to intialize main class com.help.someclass  in com/google/gson/jsonelement

Comment: Avoid relative paths because the current working directory may not be what you expect.

Comment: Can you please help how to avoid the relative paths and how can I give the correct path so that if I run form any directory it should work

Comment: Use an absolute path instead which starts with a drive letter or two backslashes on Windows or one or two forward slashes on other systems.